# Share Internet Connection in OSX regardless of interface

Tags: macos, networking, router, internet

My setup is mac osx mountain lion and a cisco linksys router. I want to share internet from osx to cisco router. Internet Sharing in "Sharing" of System Preferences works. But you have to select two interface, "from" and "to". But i have several devices, and the internet source varies time to time. So everytime i have to change the "from" interface.

I want to share it in a way that sharing wouldn't be bind to a single "from" interface. Traffic from router should pass through whichever interface is currently active.